# How to declare TS type with properties named from an existing array of strings?

Tags: typescript, types, type-conversion, mapped-types

As I understand, it's possible to create a type which conforms to array of property names like so

```
type myDynamicMappedType = {
    [key : string] : any
}
let myMappedObject : myDynamicMappedType = {
    "key1" : "val1",
    "key2" : "val2"
};
// result myVal.key1 === "val1"
```

However, I don't understand how to create a type based on an existing array of values, to use the values as property names

```
const propertiesForType: string[] = [
    "myProperty1",
    "myProperty1"
];
type myTypeFromArray = {
    [/* somehow say "each value in propertiesForType" */] : any
}
let myMappedObject : myTypeFromArray = /* has to be initialized with myProperty1 and myProperty2 values. */;
// result myMappedObject.myProperty1/2 is initialized to something
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need a [const assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) to allow TS to infer the array of strings as a tuple of literal string types;

```
const propertiesForType = ["myProperty1", "myProperty2"] as const;
```

Then you can map over each element in the tuple:

```
type myTypeFromArray = {
    [K in (typeof propertiesForType)[number]]: any;
};
```

and use the resulting type:

```
let myMappedObject: myTypeFromArray = {
    myProperty1: 42,
    myProperty2: true,
};
```

In this case, you can also use a [Record](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type) to shorten the code:

```
type myTypeFromArray = Record<(typeof propertiesForType)[number], any>;
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBADgJxHApgqBLFEBiIEAqAnqjALwwDaARALZEAKSq6RAjNQDQx2PNpQiAJmoBdGAEMIMUJCgBuAFCLBpesVQ4ktAIIIEEouRgAlFKAQATADwAKVShAAzeP3RZc+DSgCUlMACutABGaKLcEmBEAHxKigA2KLD0ALIScKiWAPLBAFbmUABcMOokKFoguvqGxgDeijCNJXzIAuzFACxCnA1N9EytrELFUAgBKD0AvkpAA)

Answer (score 1):

I hope this help you:

```
enum Keys {
  Key1 = "key1",
  Key2 = "key2",
  Key3 = "key3",
}

type myDynamicMappedType = {
    [K in Keys] : string
}
let myMappedObject: myDynamicMappedType = {
[Keys.Key1]: "val1",
[Keys.Key2]: "val2",
[Keys.Key3]: "val3"
};
```

Comment: alternatively you can use an array instead enum, but the code will be a little bit different